# hide entered value of password after form submit

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have a login form.

It contains of 2 field: login and password.

```
<form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="login" value="">
      <input type="password" name="password" value="">

      <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I want to hide entered value of password after form submit

see https://postimg.org/image/qvdftdnzl/

as you see user can look at entered password via firebug

In other words I want noone can get this value

Is it possible?

Thanks for help

Comment: You want to hide user password from himself? :)

Comment: I am trying to prevent the theft of user data  (like cross-site scripting attacks)

Comment: You do realize the information is only visible to the browser who posts the data, right?

Comment: Are you sure some malicious program can't get user data? I just try to prevent such situation

Comment: There are various javascript functions you can use that on form submission will hash the plaintext data prior to POSTing the data and send the hashed data across the wire, making the data less prone to observation. But this really is only secure in itself, if done through a TLS connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide it from the browser, that's just how HTTP works. You could use HTTPS however.

Comment: Hmm..
I've checked at https://google.com/ 
// I tried to login
I can see entered data via firebug
Although google uses HTTPS

Comment: I don't think you get it - you will always be able to see your own POST data as it is unencrypted at your own browsers end, but if you use HTTPS it's (pretty much) hidden from others.